# PHP. Регулярное выражение, допускающее отсутствие некоторых частей

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, типа: "Осталось  10 часов 15 минут 12 секунд". Некоторые компоненты (часы, минуты, секунды) могут отсутствовать. Нужно выдернуть циферки и соотнести с часами, минутами, секундами.
Делаю так:

```
Осталось\s+(?!(\d+)\s+(час).*?)(?!(\d+)\s+(минут).*?)(?!(\d+)\s+(секунд).*?)
```

Текст подходит под регулярное выражение, но от него всегда остается только "Осталось  " при любых комбинациях час., мин., сек.

P.S. Нашел информацию по `(?!...)`. Они, оказывается, используются только для проверки, но ничего не выводят.

Каким образом можно одновременно проверить наличие фрагментов и выдернуть данные?

Comment: Вы неправильно подходите к самой задаче. Регулярные выражения - это не серебряная пуля, и они хороши только в отдельных, *регулярных* случаях. Здесь же нужно написать микропарсер с логикой, чтобы не сломать мозг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать комбинацию из проверяемой части и захватывающей части. Примерно вот так:

`Осталось\s+((?<hours>\d+)\s+час(а|ов)?\s*)?((?<minutes>\d+)\s+минут(а|ы)?\s*)?((?<seconds>\d+)\s+секунд(а|ы)?)?`

После обработки в именованных группах будут требуемые значения.

Демо [тут](https://regex101.com/r/sL0fG7/3) (спасибо за наводку @stribizhev)

Comment: Окончания мне не нужны, поэтому сокращаю.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, Вы путаете необязательные группы с блоками предварительного просмотра (look-ahead). Вместо `(?!...)` надо использовать `(?:...)?`, а окончания отлавливать с помощью `\p{L}*`:

```
Осталось\s+(?:(\d+)\s+час\p{L}*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s+минут\p{L}*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s+секунд\p{L}*)?
            ^^                  ^
```

Код:

```
$re = '/Осталось\s+(?:(\d+)\s+час\p{L}*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s+минут\p{L}*)?(?:\s*(\d+)\s+секунд\p{L}*)?/u';
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/sL0fG7/1)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Где бы почитать про (?:...)? Обычно в статьях, справочниках рассказывается о простейших вещах.

Comment: Это правда, я сам недавно копался в сети, с трудом что-то нашёл на англоязычных сайтах. Ищите информацию о "незахватывающих подмасках".

Comment: А можно узнать, чем моё выражение Вас не устроило? Моё выражение в семантическом плане идентично выражению Vespera, а я всё-таки предложил решение раньше.

Comment: @stribizhev Может результат парсить удобнее?

Comment: Это когда тонна элементов в массиве? Не думаю.

Comment: @stribizhev, все-таки удобнее - ассоциативные элементы на выходе - можно сразу к ним обращаться, иначе бы пришлось выдергивать имена параметров (час минут секунд) и делать соответствие.